# How can I disable TCP window scaling?

Tags: windows-7, tcp

I had previously been using Ubuntu 11.10 and recently, Ubuntu 12.04. However, due to a stupid mistake on my part, I was forced to reinstall Windows 7.

One of a multitude of problems is that my download speeds seem to be slower on Windows 7.

On Ubuntu, I was reaching my ISP advertised speed of 25mbps. On Windows, I am stuck at 1.2mb/s. I have researched this reasonably but, I am completely lost. The problem, while looking online, seems to be window scaling.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_window_scale_option

I just need a guide to disable this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Answer was linked to](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/934430) in the Wikipedia article you linked to.

> To disable auto-tuning, follow these steps:
>
> Click Start, click All Programs, and then click Accessories.
>
> Right-click Command Prompt, and then click Run as Administrator. If you are prompted for an administrator password or confirmation, type the password or provide confirmation.
>
> At the command prompt, type the following command, and then press ENTER:
>
> netsh interface tcp set global autotuninglevel=disabled
>
> This command disables the Receive Window Auto-Tuning feature.
>
> Close the Command Prompt window.
>
> Restart the computer.

Comment: It seems as though the problem wasn't TCP window scaling. Regardless, you have answered my question. Thank you very much.

Comment: What was it? Just curious.

Comment: No idea...yet. ;)
I'll figure it out eventually. Though, TCP window limiting was a factor, disabling it only improved my download speed by 0.2 mb/s.